# SharePoint Web Part: Hide OOB Editor Part Categories (e.g. Appearance, Layout)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am developing a custom web part for SharePoint 2010 wherein I need to hide the OOB editor part categories like Appearance, Layout etc..

I tried  overriding the  CreateEditorParts() method of the WebPart class and return an empty EditorPartCollection collection but this doesn’t seem to work.

Appreciate any pointers to achieve the same.